# Cannot resolve import for OAuth2 class on Java

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, oauth

I'm following this step by step tutorial by google:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

I have downloaded  Google APIs client library for Java that it mentions and I have added Jars from Properties > Build Path > Add External Jars on Eclipse. I added all the jar files cointained into "libs" folder.

But when I write this line, at backend code side,

```
Oauth2 oauth2 = new Oauth2.Builder(
```

I cannot resolve the import properly, and it says:

> Oauth2 cannot be resolved to a type

The list of jar files contained in "libs" is:

> google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar 
>   google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-api-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-api-client-gson-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-api-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-api-client-java6-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-api-client-protobuf-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-api-client-servlet-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-api-client-xml-1.18.0-rc.jar google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-oauth-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-oauth-client-java6-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-oauth-client-java7-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-oauth-client-jetty-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-oauth-client-servlet-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-http-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-http-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-http-client-protobuf-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-http-client-gson-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-http-client-jackson-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-http-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-http-client-jdo-1.18.0-rc.jar
>   google-http-client-xml-1.18.0-rc.jar commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
>   gson-2.1.jar httpclient-4.0.1.jar httpcore-4.0.1.jar
>   jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar jackson-core-2.1.3.jar jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
>   jsr305-1.3.9.jar protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar transaction-api-1.1.jar
>   xpp3-1.1.4c.jar

Any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: `I added all the jar files` can you post a list of the JARs you added? Also if you could show us the OAuth2 imports for that class, that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the following jars:

```
google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
google-oauth-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc
google-oauth-client-java6-1.18.0-rc
google-oauth-client-jetty-1.18.0-rc
google-oauth-client-servlet-1.18.0-rc
```

Which can be found here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/oauth2/v2
in the lib folder

Comment: I think there is still a jar file that I didn't import, since it says "The import com.google.api.services cannot be resolved"

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/oauth2/v2 Did you try the download link here?

Comment: Yes, I see it now! You're missing a the Oauth2 specific jar files from that library.

Comment: yes, I had tried, but I didn't import all the jar files. Now I did it, and worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/oauth2/v2 was changed, there is no lib folder for now. You can download jars directly from https://mvnrepository.com/